# Como declaro una variable de javascript desde webdriver con selenium y python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

estoy intentando declarar una funcion de javascript desde python con selenium, parecido a esto.

```
driver.execute_script("return function aaa(){console.log('Hola mundo')}")
```

pero cuando uso `driver.execute_script("aaa()")` no funciona.

Como declaro una funcion que se pueda llamar desde python??

Answer (score 1):

Para declarar una variable tienes que usar `var =`.

Como ejemplo voy a definir una función que va a definir una variable `x` y dentro de un loop va a incrementar su valor hasta que `i` llegue a 5. Al finalizar retornará la variable `x`.

```
x = browser.execute_script('''
function foo(){
    var x=0; 
    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        x+=1;
    } 
    return x;
}
return foo();''')
```

Luego en python puedes hacer `print(x)` y la salida por pantalla será `5`.

Comment: Pero ocupo llamar la funcion en distintas partes de el codigo, por lo que no tiene caso hacer eso.
Tuviera que copiar y pegar el código entero cada que la quiero llamar.